Theory of semiotic mediation in teaching math at high school
I am working on the theory of semiotic mediation in teaching math at high school. According to the theory I need an artefact that is appropriate for high school (secondary school). In many papers there are examples about elementary school (an artefact was a compass, for instance).

Could you please include in your post a little about what semiotic mediation is?

Maybe the definition is not settled. As I understand, in mediation, the use of concrete tools changes the nature of labor: in preparing the soil, the human works the tool, and the tool works the earth. The tool mediates human labor. In semiotic mediation signs mediate cognition. (Per Vygotsky.) A compass is not a sign but a tool. Its use may well mediate understanding, but it does not look like semiotic mediation. Semiotic mediation would concern how $\bot$ and $\Vert$ affect our understanding of geometry; or even more basically, how the terms perpendicular and parallel do.

In this view, many answers on MESE rely on the analysis of semiotic mediation, albeit without using the education-jargon phrase. -- Now what would be an artefact in this case, if not a compass or a calculator? I'm not sure. Usually I think of it as something produced by the student(s) possibly in collaboration with the teacher. Possibly a video of a classroom activity (discussion using the terms of the subject is semiotic mediation).

"...any artifact will be referred to as tool of semiotic mediation as long as it is (or it is conceived to be) intentionally used by the teacher to mediate a mathematical content through a designed didactical intervention" (Bartolini Bussi/Mariotti 2008) in Semiotics in Theory and Practice in Mathematics Education. It is broader than the definition given by @user1815 and explicitly connects back to tools that are not signs.

BTW, I find it slightly embarrassing that a question on a site for educators has been closed for using a standard term in the theory of education. Given the OP's struggle to express their question in English, I wonder if the community couldn't figure out a way to be a little more welcoming and inclusive.

What is the question?

@user12357: I suspect that many here are teachers of mathematics but not necessarily familiar with the theory of education or perhaps only familiar with certain parts of it.

@user12357: (continuing the above comment) It is the question asker's responsibility to provide sufficient details/clarity and ours to ask for clarification where thought desirable or necessary. Naturally there can be gray areas and misunderstandings about the community here but this isn't intended to be unwelcoming, although I can see that it might be perceived as such at times.

@JW I agree that it would be minimally polite to respond to simple requests like yours, and it irritates me when users don't. OTOH, when they don't I have to wonder why. My offensiveness, their rudeness, their laziness? Tough to judge. Given their polite response to Justin's answer, I think it's none of the above. Rather, given the difficulty expressing themselves in the OP, I think it a big hurdle for the user, and a satisfactory answer came along before they did anything about it. - On other sites (MSE, e.g.) there are questions about areas some don't know but others do. They're not closed.

@JRN I think asserting that "I need a..." is not implicitly "What is a...?" is nit-picky.

Here's what I understand to be the definition of semiotic mediation:

The process that sees the use of the artifacts and signs as the center of human activity. In mathematics, the tool becomes a mediator between intuitive knowledge and scientific knowledge.

In this view, I find it hard to disagree with a calculator being a suitable artifact for high school.
Does it mediate between intuitive knowledge and scientific knowledge? You bet!

$12 \times 4 = 48.$ That's intuitive.
$123 \times 456 = 56088.$ That's scientific.

The calculator is allows you to go from an intuitive understanding of arithmetic, to a scientific understanding.
In fact, you can use the calculator as a tool to perform scientific "experiments" with arithmetic and develop an intuitive understanding of the results.
For instance, you can do the following on a calculator:
\begin{align*}
&11^2 \phantom{111} = 121 \\
&111^2 \phantom{11} = 12321 \\
&1111^2 \phantom{1} = 1234321 \\
&11111^2 = 123454321
\end{align*}
Woah, that's interesting! The calculator helped us develop an intuitive understanding of $111...1^n.$
Keep going with this line of experimentation and you'll also find connections to Pascal's triangle:
\begin{align*}
&11^2 = 121 \\
&11^3 = 1331 \\
&11^4 = 14641 \\
&11^5 = 161051 \\
&\phantom{11^5} = \mathbf{1} + \mathbf{5} \cdot 10 + \mathbf{10}\cdot 100 + \mathbf{10}\cdot 1000 + \mathbf{5}\cdot 10000 + \mathbf{1}\cdot 100000
\end{align*}
Why does this happen? Look at the binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}
11^n &= (10+1)^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot 10^n \cdot 1^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \cdot 10^n
\end{align*}
You can do similar experiments graphing functions on Desmos, Geogebra, or a graphing calculator.
All this to say, I don't think you have to contort yourself to check a box on the "semiotic mediation" requirement. Chances are you're already teaching some lesson(s) in which a calculator or graphing utility becomes a mediator between intuitive and scientific knowledge.

Maybe writing down an equation and manipulating algebraically, writing down the steps, it is another example. I am not familiar with the theory, but this would seem to fit the short definition your quoted.

@Tommi I personally think your suggestion would qualify, and that this "semiotic mediation" requirement is just a bunch of fluffy nonsense -- but I could also imagine a persnickety education standards auditor having an issue. When you have a calculator that's a physical thing you can point to and say "look, this physical object is the artifact that we're using." Having the physical object to point to means you're better shielded against attacks.

Semiotics is a known branch of humanities. The idea of semiotic mediation can be valuable as a theoretical tool, in much the same way many other humanities ideas are valuable for giving and emphasizing a particular perspective on some part of culture or human behaviour. However, this question does not seem to make a strong use of the concept.

@Tommi I'm aware of all this. My point is that yes, as you say, the question does not seem to make a strong use of the concept -- because this is not really a setting where the concept is valuable. OP is being made to follow some standards checklist that contains a silly requirement. I'm not saying that the object of the requirement (semiotic mediation) is silly -- just that the requirement itself is silly in this situation.

Thanks a lot @JustinSkycak. According to that theory, if the teacher wants to use some different objects (for example balls with different colours)...those object can be considereted as artefacts? right?

@ryuk I think so, as long as you're actually doing something where they are needed to mediate between intuitive and scientific knowledge, and they're not just supplementary to the lesson.

@ryuk, Justin: Bussi et al., Semiotic Mediation in Mathematics and Physics Classrooms: Artifacts and Signs after a Vygotskian Approach explcitly mentions calculators as artifacts (p. 4). (+1)

Thanks a lot! @user12357
